# There is no immersion of the Möbius band in the plane.

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

There is no immersion of the Möbius band in the plane.

I believe we have to work with the tangent bundle of the Möbius band, but I'm not getting no useful result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $f:M\to\Bbb R^2$ is a differentiable map from the Möbius band to the plane, then for the standard volume form $\omega=dx\wedge dy$ on $R^2$, its pull back via $f$, denoted by $f^*\omega$, induces a $2$-form on $M$. Since $M$ is not orientable, $f^*\omega=0$ at some $p\in M$, so   the tangent map of  $f$ is degenerate at $p$. That is to say, $f$ cannot be an immersion.

Comment: Nice!I thought we need to use the non-triviality of tangent bundle, but this way we get what we need in a beautiful way. Thanks

Comment: Does the definition of "immersion" require differentiability?  (I just realized the only definition of "immersion" that I know is a crude and vulgar thing that's not actually a definition---something like this: "It's like an embedding except that self-intersections are allowed."  But there must be more to it, since otherwise just mapping the whole thing to a single point would be allowed, and then _everything_ would be immersible.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy One only needs that the derivative of the map is injective at every point in the manifold being immersed. That is, the induced map on tangent spaces is injective.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I understand the term [**immersion**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics)) in the same way as  Daniel Rust said.

Comment: @DanielRust : Does that mean it has to be locally one-to-one everywhere?  If so, could one drop all requirements about differentiability and just require it to be continuous and everywhere locally one-to-one?

Comment: It is also true that, say, there is no continuous injective map from the (closed or open) band to the plane. You cannot prove it using differential forms, though :-)

Comment: The Wikipedia article requires differentiability right at the beginning.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : Since it said "immersion" and not "embedding", shouldn't one say "locally injective" rather than "injective"?

Comment: There are several meanings attached to the term,, Micheal. Wikipedia must be talking about **one** of them.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I agree with you, but judging from the tags(and absence of the injectivity condition), I believe OP is interested in the differentiable case

Comment: It is also true that there is no continuous locally injective map from the (closed or open) band to the plane. There is no reason why one **should** talk about locally injective instead of injective...